# Get value from a textBox in Datalist linked with event button

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

This is my datalist:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
               RepeatLayout="Flow">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:Label ID="IdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  Visible="False" />
                Titre:
                <asp:Label ID="TitreLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Titre") %>' />
                <br />
                Description:
                <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                <br />

                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                 ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "Handler.ashx?ID={0}") %>' Width="200" Height="200"/>

                <br />
                comments:
                <asp:Label ID="commentsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("comments") %>' />
                <br />

                Ajouter commentaire 
                <asp:button ID="btnAjouter"  runat="server" OnCommand="Button_Command"
                 CommandName="add" Text="Ajouter" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxComments" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br/>
                <br/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

This my aspx.vb button event:

```
Sub Button_Command(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs)
    Dim connectionString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BecsEtMuseauxSQL").ConnectionString
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

    con.Open()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("updateComments", con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    //I try this ....
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DataList1.FindControl("IdLabel").ToString()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Comments", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DataList1.FindControl("TextBoxComments").ToString()

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub
```

I get an error like this: "The object reference is not definied to an object instance"

How can I catch the value from the label IdLabel and TextBoxComments in this situation?

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DataList1.FindControl("IdLabel").ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Comments", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DataList1.FindControl("TextBoxComments").ToString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the [DataList's ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemcommand%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead of the Button's Command.

Then you can find your controls with `e.Item.FindControl`:

```
Private Sub DataList1_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListCommandEventArgs) _
    Handles DataList1.ItemCommand
    If e.CommandName = "add" Then
        Dim IdLabel = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("IdLabel"), Label)
        Dim TextBoxComments = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("TextBoxComments"), TextBox)
        ' ... '
    End If
End Sub
```

on aspx, remove your redundant `Command`-handler:

```
<asp:button ID="btnAjouter" CommandName="add"  Text="Ajouter" runat="server" />
```

If you want to use the Button's Click-Event instead, that's possible also.

```
Protected Sub btnAjouter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim container = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, Control).NamingContainer, DataListItem)
    Dim IdLabel = DirectCast(container.FindControl("IdLabel"), Label)
    Dim TextBoxComments = DirectCast(container.FindControl("TextBoxComments"), TextBox)
    ' ... '
End Sub
```

on aspx, add the click-event handler to the button:

```
<asp:button ID="btnAjouter" OnClick="btnAjouter_Click" Text="Ajouter" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I have to remplace the Sub Button_Command(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs) ???

Comment: The way shown in your previous question was to handle the DataList's ItemCommand event instead of the Button's Command event. I've showed you two ways here. 1. Handle the DataList's ItemCommand(preferred) 2. Handle the Button's Click event. I assume that you've mixed both.